# Port a live system from App Engine Helper to App Engine Patch

Tags: google-app-engine, session, google-cloud-datastore, patch, helper

I am running a live system that is currently serving about 20K pages a day which is based on App Engine Helper (Python) with session support provided by AppEngine utilities.

One problem that I have been having is that sessions are occasionally randomly logging out. I would like to try using the App Engine Patch, since it has "native" django session support, but I am worried that this is possibly going to be like doing a brain transplant. Specifically, current database models are all inhereted from BaseModel provided by the App Engine Helper. While, App Engine Patch does not have this inheritance.

Does anyone know if it is possible to migrate a live system from App Engine Helper to App Engine Patch? If so, do you have any advice or warnings that I should heed, before attempting this transition?

Thank you and kind regards
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think about porting your system not to [App Engine Patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/) but to [Django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) (by app-engine-patch authors).

I moved from google-app-engine-django and app-engine-patch to Django-nonrel is because first two are not maintained any more.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigations, I discovered that newer versions of Django and App Engine Helper have built in support for sessions. After migrating to this system, my problems of randomly losing sessions have been resolved.

Alex